# How to get date from DB and place in fullcalendar using servlet

Tags: java, servlets, fullcalendar

I am first time using fullcalendar in my application.I just trying to place all events from DB to fullcalendar.Here is my code what i tried,

```
MyJsp.jsp

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                //defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
                editable: true,
                events: "/FullcalendarProject/FullCalendarChecking"
        });
```

FullCalendarChecking.java

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            List l = new ArrayList();

            PreparedStatement st = null;
            ResultSet rst = null;
            Connection con = null;

            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/raptor1_5","root","");
                String query="select * from tblplanner where User_id=?";
                st = con.prepareStatement(query);
                st.setString(1, "112");
                rst =st.executeQuery();

                while(rst.next())
                {
                    System.out.println("entered...");
                    String plannedDate =rst.getString("date"); // this will be start in fullcalendar
                    String plannedChapter =rst.getString("chapter"); // this will be title in fullcalendar
                    l.add(plannedDate);
                    l.add(plannedChapter);
                    //here i am doing woring..?!!
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
          finally
          {
            try{
            con.close();
            rst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


             response.setContentType("application/json");
             response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
             PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
             out.write(new Gson().toJson(l));   

        }
```

But this code not working like what i am expecting.

**Output :**

```
all fetched dates dsiaplays in todays date
```

**Expected output :**

```
all fetched dates show in its own date
```

**MyTable :**

**User_id     chapter       date**

112           somechapter1   2015-04-27

112           somechapter2   2015-04-29

112           somechapter3   2015-04-30

how to do this?

Comment: please share your array that is being fetched.

Comment: @Franky the array i am getting [2015-04-09, Plants, 2015-04-10, Plants, 2015-04-12, Plants2, 2015-04-13, Plants3, 2015-04-08, Plants4, 2015-04-12, Animals]

Comment: your array is not correct it should be like this `[{title: 'Event1',start: '2011-04-04'}, {title  : 'event2', start  : '2010-01-05',  end  : '2010-01-07'}]`

Comment: ya you are right but i dont know how to achieve like this [{title: 'Event1',start: '2011-04-04'}, {title : 'event2', start : '2010-01-05', end : '2010-01-07'}] from db. give me sample code

Comment: @Franky I have data in DB only User_id, chapter and date so how can i form like this [{title: 'chaptername',start: '2011-04-04'}, {title : 'chapter2', start : '2010-01-05', },{title :'chpater3',start : '2010-01-07'}].